# How to find specific text string in nested tar.gz archives?

Tags: regex, windows, winapi, windows-7, tar

How to find specific text string in source code files packed into nested .tar.gz archives, packed inside anothe rar archive(48MB)? (on Windows 7) I tried to use LookDisk, but it hangs and crash. Is it possible to find use system **findstr** utility, and what's regular expressions for this? Or with other search utility, that do not need installation(portable).

Comment: If those are nested archives, then you might be better off extracting everything and then searching.

Comment: Within an archive one would expect a string to be present only as a compressed binary representation of itself, further this representation will be non-deterministic in as much as it will be influenced by other arbitrary data present in the archive so you cannot determine what to search for from the input string alone. You would need to decompress the data, then search.

Answer (score 1):

Based on a [SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/a/546694/66769) this example batch file searches multiple `.tar.gz` archive files (specified on the command line) and outputs the filename of the `.tar.gz` containing specified string.

It does this without outputting any files to disk.

It is dependant on 7-Zip, you can use a portable version of this - it doesn't need to be "installed" - but be available.

Change the value of the variable `SEARCHSTR` (currently `hell`) to the string you want to search for.

I can't see any obvious or easy way of returning the filename of the file containing the text inside the archive.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set SEARCHSTR=hell

rem Ensure 7z.exe is in your path or in current directory... ie. set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\7-Zip

rem Loop through all commandline args - the tar.gz files
for %%i in (%*) do (

    rem Extract without an intermediate .tar
    7z x "%%i" -so | 7z x -si -ttar -so | findstr /C:"%SEARCHSTR%"

    if "!ERRORLEVEL!" == "0" (
      set FOUNDIN=%%i

      rem Exit after we find the first occurrence.
      goto found
    )
)


:notfound
echo Unable to locate search string "%SEARCHSTR%" in specified files.
goto end

:found
echo Found search string "%SEARCHSTR%" in "%FOUNDIN%".

:end
```

## Edit 1 - Using self contained / portable 7-Zip

Download the official `7-Zip Command Line Version` one listed on the [Official 7-Zip Download page](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) extract and use `7za.exe` it's a self-contained command line version of 7-Zip, meaning you won't need any extra files just `7za.exe`.

You will need to change the two occurrences of `7z` to `7za` to use this version.
So the line:

```
7z x "%%i" -so | 7z x -si -ttar -so | findstr /C:"%SEARCHSTR%"
```

Changes to:

```
7za x "%%i" -so | 7za x -si -ttar -so | findstr /C:"%SEARCHSTR%"
```

Comment: 7-Zip is in the same directory with RAR archive: how should be this line? `rem C:\7-ZipPortable_9.20_Rev_3.paf`

Comment: Please see `Edit 1` in the answer `Using self contained / portable 7-Zip`.

Comment: If you wanted to search for "long password" you would change it to "set SEARCHSTR=long password"